# Java Swing: overlay components for light and heavyweight components?

Tags: java, swing, overlay

Are there any good overlay component library for both lightweight and heavyweight components?

Is this achievable with JLabel even with highest opacity setting?

The overlay component needs to be placed over any part of the component and display text.

Something like http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm Overlayable component. I am not sure if the license allows you to use it for commercial purposes.

It'd be if there was animation and effect support like, fade-in, fade-out, shake etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree with @Andrew Thompson answer, use [Window](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) rather than some 'OverLayable Whatever', but in this case this container will be always on the Top, over Swing Container.

Since that's allowed from JDK1.6_0_12, I still highly recommend don't mixing AWT with Swing in the one Swing Container, for any reasons what there exists.

Answer (score 2):

See [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

> Historically, in the Java language, mixing heavyweight and lightweight components in the same container has been problematic. However, as of the JDK 6 Update 12 and JDK 7 build 19 releases, mixing heavyweight and lightweight components is easy to accomplish. This article explains some details you might need to know.

I expect that should work with most 'overlay components'.